# How to use Class Initialize so that application opens in beginning,run all the tests & closes in the end

Tags: coded-ui-tests

My code:

1. This is initialize method
   [TestInitialize()]
   public void MyTest Initialize()
   {}
2. This is test 1
   [TestMethod]
   public void Validate_Create_Command()
   { }
3. This is test 2
   [TestMethod]
   public void Validate_Delete_Command()
   {}
   Right Now test1 opens application & closes the application & 
   test2 also opens the application & closes.
   My question is how to open application once & close application after all tests completes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would recommend you always open at the beginning of the test and close at the end. Your recordings should be flexible enough that you can combine them to navigate to different parts of the app. I'll answer how best to do that in a moment first your actual question.

If you want to open at the start and close at the end I use this pattern

```
[TestClass]
public class Tests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
     UIMap.ClickNext();
     UIMap.ClickPlusButton();
     UIMap.AssertStuff();
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod2()
    {
     UIMap.ClickNext();
     UIMap.ClickMinusButton();
     UIMap.AssertStuff();
    }

    [ClassInitialize()]
    public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext testcontext)
    {        
        Utilities.Launch();
    }

    [ClassCleanup()]
    public static void ClassCleanup()
    {        
        Utilities.Close();
    }
}

public static class Utilities
{
    private static ApplicationUnderTest App;
    public static Launch()
    {
         try
         {
              App = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(pathToExe);
         }
         catch (Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToLaunchApplicationException e) {} 
    }
    public static Close()
    {
        App.Close();
        App = null;
    }
}
```

To do this on a test to test basis you simple use the normal (below)
[TestInitialize()] and [TestCleanup()]

Comment: Zaq I'm getting an error called object is not instantiated while running the test.

Comment: I just tried in my own env and I got what you're talking about. I've seen in before and the fix I generally use is added in above. Basically you can the failed to launch exception and ignore it since the app actually launches fine. In the case where it doesn't your test is going to fail anyways to it's okay.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to re-record test 1 and test 2 to no longer open/close the application.

In TestInitialize, record the launching of your application.
In TestCleanup, record the closing of your application.

What will happen when you run the CodedUI test is:

- Step 1: TestInitialize runs which launches your application
- Step 2: Test1 and Test2 run (again, you will have removed
  launching/closing of your app)
- Step 3: TestCleanup runs which closes your application

  ```
  #region Additional test attributes

  //Use TestInitialize to run code before running each test 
  [TestInitialize()]
  public void MyTestInitialize()
  {        
   this.UIMap.OpenMyApplication();
  }

  //Use TestCleanup to run code after each test has run
  [TestCleanup()]
  public void MyTestCleanup()
  {        
   this.UIMap.CloseMyApplication();
  }

  #endregion
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You could copy the method calls to launch and close the application from the test methods into the initialize and cleanup methods, then delete the calls from the test methods.

The way that Coded UI managed applications between test cases changed between Visual Studio 2010 and 2012, also the way that `CloseOnPlaybackCleanup` worked. For more details see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/11/08/using-same-applicationundertest-browserwindow-across-multiple-tests.aspx