# Coded UI closes the application after each test method

Tags: .net, mstest, coded-ui-tests

when I run coded UI tests, the Desktop based `WPF` application closes after every `[TestMethod]` making it impossible to run tests in sequence using the same Application meaning that the same steps will have to be repeated for every test.  I used to have multiple scripts that could be run either independently or, by switching a flag, in sequence, one test continuing from where the previous left off. I have tried using `CloseOnPlaybackCleanup` set to false but it does not work. I get below exception

Note: I am trying to run the tests through mstest.exe

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.ApplicationUnderTest.set_CloseOnPlaybackCleanup(Boolean)'.
```

I am using VS2010

Comment: The way that Coded UI manages applications between test cases changed between Visual Studio 2010 and 2012, also the way that CloseOnPlaybackCleanup worked. For more details see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2012/11/08/using-same-applicationundertest-browserwindow-across-multiple-tests.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The question seems similar to [How to use Class Initialize so that application opens in beginning,run all the tests & closes in the end](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491353/how-to-use-class-initialize-so-that-application-opens-in-beginning-run-all-the-t/19555631#19555631) I've provided an answer there to solve the problem